# Spring Boot application payment method

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, paypal, stripe-payments, credit-card

I am currently the back-end part of a Spring Boot application and i am willing to integrate a payment method. But I can't seem to find the right payment option. I am a beginner in app development and working solo. Do you have any suggestions?

APPLICATION:
I am developing a platform where users can rent a car for a certain period of time. The application will have a react and android application on the frontend. The users can see the different locations of the available cars on a map within the react and android app. They can make a reservation for a car and unlock, drive and lock it after usage.

PAYMENT METHOD:
I am looking for a payment where the users admits to the payment when unlocking the car, but the price of the ride is not known yet. When the user is finished using the car, the price of the ride will be determined by the distance and time driven by the user.

POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:
-PayPal: there is a possibility to let the user authorize a payment, but capture the funds later. The funds can be altered but only after three days and with a maximum value of 115 percent.
-CreditCard: I read in a lot of posts that storing creditcard information in a database is a big NO.
-Stripe: Don't really know, possible option?

Are there any solutions/examples of how this problem can be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PayPal: there is a possibility to let the user authorize a payment, but capture the funds later. The funds can be altered but only after three days and with a maximum value of 115 percent.

There is no need to wait 3 days, that is a misreading of the [authorization and capture documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/admin/auth-capture/). If you have a need to capture over 115% of the initial authorization, contact PayPal about this. But a simple solution is to authorize something close to the maximum value of what you will need to dependably capture.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. On the site they state the following "An authorization places a hold on the funds and is valid for 29 days. After a successful authorization, PayPal recommends that you capture the funds within the three-day honor period. Success of the capture is subject to risk and availability of funds on the authorized funding instrument. Within the 29-day authorization period, you can issue multiple re-authorizations after the honor period expires.". How should I interpret "you can issue multiple re authorizations after the honor period expires?

Comment: You can do a reauthorization request to get a new 3 day honor period. Reauthorizations are virtually never needed, and are probably the most useless API call/feature. Simply do your capture attempt regardless.

Comment: How can I Capture a different amount than the amount of my authorized order. In the documentation I don't see an 'amount' attribute in the captureOrder API. When I try to patch I get the error that the order is already completed.

Comment: Create an order with intent:authorize, capture the order, and then capture the authorization.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me, I am trully becoming desperate. So I succeeded creating the order with intent Authorize, then letting the user approve it. Than I authorized the Order. But in the Order API I can only see the possibility to capture an order/payment. I don't see two capture possibilities. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read the API response? There is a rel:capture link in the payment -> authorization object that is returned when you capture the order. You use the payments API to capture authorizations, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/#authorizations_capture

Comment: I have read a lot but I am reading a lot of wrong things I guess. So the thing where I am now stuk is the followin. I create an order, the payer approves the order, I then authorize the order. In the response of the order authorization I am getting payment details with a payment authorizationId. When i than call the capture api from orders with the payment authorization Id it directly captures the money and I don't get any links to capture a payment which seems fair. So do i have to use the payment authorizationId in  the payments API to capture a different amount?

Comment: My previous comment has the information for capturing a different value

Comment: I want to make a CaptureRequest but now I don't see where I can pass my payment ID in the CaptureRequest from the payment API https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK/blob/develop/checkout-sdk/src/main/java/com/paypal/payments/CaptureRequest.java

Comment: I don't see it in that SDK either. But it's part of the API.

Comment: Okay thanks, then I will construct the request myself. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has the ability to [place a hold on a card and then capture funds up to 7 days later](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later) for the amount you captured or less.

> Place a hold on a card to reserve funds now but only capture them after your business completes the service. For example, a hotel may authorize a payment in full prior to a guest’s arrival, then move the money when the guest checks out.
>
> When a payment is authorized, the bank guarantees the amount and holds it on the customer’s card for up to seven days.

You could place a hold for the maximum amount you expect to charge for the ride (say $50) then capture the actual amount when the ride completes (perhaps $23.50).